# Syntax Error: Unexpected token < React render

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, syntax-error, token

I setup a router in Express like this:

```
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var quotes = require('../model/quotes');
var user = require('../model/users');
var auth = require('../lib/auth');
var React=require('react');
var ReactDOMServer=require('react-dom/server')
var Homepage=React.createFactory(require('../component/index.js').Homepage);

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        if (req.user) {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
            var HomepageHTML=ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Homepage({}));
            res.render('index',{homepage:HomepageHTML});
        }
    });

}
```

The `index` page which will be sent as response, written in swig template engine

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block title %}Homepage{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{homepage}}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the `Homepage` component written in React:

```
var React=require('react');

var Homepage=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div className="homepage-content">
                <div className="left">
                    <img src={{'../public/images/img_landing_page_mac.png'}}/>
                </div>
                <div className="right">
                    <h2 style={{fontSize:'33px',letterSpacing:'5px'}}>
                        Organize <br/>Modern Knowledge<br/> for Mankind
                    </h2>
                    <p style={{fontSize:'20px',marginTop:'35px',letterSpacing:'4px'}}>
                        Consume, Collect and Revisit <br/>Knowledge at Your Fingertips
                    </p>
                    <a href="#"
                    style={{marginTop:'80px',display:'inline-block',marginLeft:'-17px'}}>
                        <img src={{'../public/images/btn_get_chrome.png'}}/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

exports.Homepage=Homepage;
```

When I started the server, I got this error and struggled in vain to solve it

```
/home/kuro/Workspace/corate/component/index.js:30
        return (<div></div>);
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kuro/Workspace/corate/routes/index.js:7:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kuro/Workspace/corate/app.js:43:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or something? You need to transpile your JSX into javascript, otherwise it will hit a syntax error on the first `<`

Comment: @azium Do you mean I need to use webpack or browserify to bundle my React code and then include the bundled output in html?

Comment: @azium Your comment reminded me. Thanks

Comment: You don't *need* browserify or webpack--although those are very helpful. What you need is to transform your JSX code into JavaScript which requires Babel or another transformer (but typically Babel).

Comment: @azium I edited my question. I used `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`. I want to render this on server-side. It still encounters the same error. Did I miss anything?

Comment: yes: you still aren't using a transpiler, like [babel](https://babeljs.io), or a [require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) that lets node load .jsx code and transpile it to js automatically

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Oh, I tried to install and configure babel in my `package.json` and succeeded. Thanks very much